# Sliding stops working after opening scaled version of slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have a slider, and when I click on one of the images it contains, the bigger slider containing the same images is created and displayed, and all other elements are hidden.

But if I click **exactly on the first** image of the first slider and then close the bigger slider, the smaller slider stops working: sliding doesn't work.

I noticed that if I disable `autoplay` property of the first slider, everything works just fine.

jsfiddle of the case when autoplay is **enabled** (not working): https://jsfiddle.net/seLn6c3w/

jsfiddle of the case when autoplay is **disabled** (working): https://jsfiddle.net/0dkqubc1/28/

**How can I make everything work fine even if autoplay property of the first slider is enabled?**

**UPD:**
The error occurs if you slide through the bigger slides a bit and only then close the bigger slider